# Equality of All Elements in A Range

Tags: algorithm, range, d, equality

What Phobos algorithm should I use to check if all elements in a range are equal or not? I've looked in `std.algorithm` and the closest I've found is `equal` but it takes two ranges as argument. I also cannot find a way to apply `reduce` to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use canFind:

```
import std.algorithm;
import std.range;

void main() {
    int[] foo = [1,1,2];
    if(!foo.empty) {
      if(!canFind!"a != b"(foo, foo.front))
           // they are equal
      else
            // not equal
    } else { /* nothing to compare against */ }
}
```

The logic here is if they are all equal, then it should *not* be able to find an item that is not equal to the first item.

Andrei's answer has several more options!

Answer (score 6):

Nice, Adam. A few more possibilities:

```
foo.empty || foo.equal(repeat(foo.front, foo.length))
```

or

```
foo.empty || repeat(foo.front).startsWith(foo)
```

or

```
foo.findAdjacent!("a != b").empty
```

Comment: ooh, I like the last one. And empty is a good point too, I used length which wouldn't work on a plain input range.

Comment: Also: `mismatch(foo, foo)[0].empty`, `uniq(foo).walkLength() == 1`, `group(foo).walkLength() == 1` (`uniq` assumes sorted, but it will work here regardless)

Comment: All these choices in life ;) BTW: What should the return value of an empty array be - true, false or exception? Maybe it doesn't matter...

Comment: @Nordlöw That would depend on what you're trying to do, but two arrays are considered equal if they're both empty. The same goes for when comparing two ranges with `equal`. And technically, every element in an empty range is equal to every other element (of course, technically, every element is also not equal to every element). But I'd go for `true`.